# Hibernate 4.1.3 multi-tenancy null pointer exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm having trouble using the new multi tenant feature of hibernate 4.1.3
I'm using Glassfish 3.1 with JPA2 and Hibernate 4.1.3 as provider.

This is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="AuroraServicePU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/sqlserver/Aurora</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="100"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value="org.dna.aurora.web.TenantResolver" />
            <property name="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="DISCRIMINATOR" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is the exception I get when try to deploy the application.

> INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final} INFO:
>   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.3.Final} INFO: HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name
>   : javassist INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [     name:
>   AuroraServicePU   ...] SEVERE: Exception while invoking class
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method SEVERE:
>   Exception while preparing the app SEVERE: The log message is null.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$MultiTenantConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:117)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2277)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2273)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:76)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:205)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:213)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:486)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:220)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:166)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:870)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:465)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:222)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:234)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>
> SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app

UPDATE:
I've read the docs again and notice this important peace of information:

> DISCRIMINATOR Correlates to the partitioned (discriminator) approach.
>   It is an error to attempt to open a session without a tenant
>   identifier using this strategy. This strategy is not yet implemented
>   in Hibernate as of 4.0 and 4.1. Its support is planned for 5.0.

Is that really means the discriminator strategy is not available right now?
Maybe this is the whole problem?

Any help will be great.
Thank you,
Ido.

Comment: I can only speculate MultiTenantConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess appears to be null this might be a bug. If it were me since this is pretty bleeding edge I'd try to get in touch with one of the guys in Hibernate's IRC tag irc.freenode.net/#hibernate or post hibernate community forum (https://forum.hibernate.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified how Hibernate should obtain connections.  Did you read the docs related to this? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e4583

And specifically:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e4658
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e4702

Comment: I did read and I have specified. I have jta-data-source element. I've looked at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e4658

Comment: Well 2 problems now that I look closer at you snippet: (1) DISCRIMINATOR is not yet supportet.  (2) Multi-tenancy is not really supported yet with JPA; the main issue with JPA support is needing to be able to tie in to the Session creation process; that has been addressed for 4.1.4 by <https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7306>.  But even in 4.1.4 you will not be able to pass in a datasource; you will instead need to follow the MultiTenantConnectionProvider directions in the docs I linked.

Comment: MultiTenantConnectionProvider means I have to have separate database for each tenant. This will be harder to maintain and will not scale as well.

Comment: And it will actually work.  Easier to maintain is kind of silly if it does not work